# A word for a person who works on two positions at the same time

Tags: single-word-requests

Like:

> "A manager and designer at the same time wanted"

It doesn't sound very informative nor does it make much sense.
How can I write this sentence so that it can be understood as I want a person that can be manager and designer at the same time?

Comment: I think it very much depends on which is the main position, the person may be hired as a manager with an additional function/responsibility as a designer for instance.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a Creative Director?

Answer (score 0):

One way, "Wanted: A person to manage >...< and design >...<", or you could reverse the two, if designing was the greater resonsibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Wanted**: A manager-[cum](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/cum)-designer

> (used for linking two nouns) and; as well as
>
> *He’s a barman-cum-waiter.*

[Oxford]

Comment: A *manager-cum-designer*?

Comment: @Josh61: Don't look at me. He's the one who wants to hire one.

Comment: Just an example guys, let's not make a fuss about that.

Comment: @Ace: No fuss, dude. We're just kidding. Happens in the comments every now and then.

Comment: @Ace: Is the "cum" bothering you? You can always hyphenate the words without it, like "soldier-poet".

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

> Wanted: manager-designer

Comment: I think that this works when the position involves equal parts "manager" and "designer." Another way to express the same idea in a visually meaningful way is with a solidus (or forward slash): _manager/designer_.